# Jarallax duration and scrolling speed

Tags: performance, parallax, duration

I can't seem to find how to control the scrolling speed and the duration of the site using jarallax. The only way I can find to control the progress is with

```
    jarallax.addAnimation('.class1',[{progress: "0%"},{progress: "20%"}];
    jarallax.addAnimation('.class2',[{progress: "20%"},{progress: "40%"}];
```

but when i change the progress to a smaller percentage it just makes the effect faster.

I need to extend the duration. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found what i was looking for... I had to edit (increase) the height attribute of the body in the .css file... Anyways thanks.